# How can I leave the NaN values unfilled on HeatmapGridSeries(LightningChart)?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I'm plotting a spectrogram using LightningChart's HeatmapGridSeries.

By default, it colors NaN values the same color as 0.

How can I leave the NaN values unfilled?

Below is my test code.

It fills NaN values with the same blue color as 0.

I'm working with the latest version of LightningChart which is 4.2.0.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Using chart in HTML page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Automatically support high DPI devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Flexbox styling to have the chart and header fill the page.
        Chart will take as much space as possible. -->
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .box {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .box .row.header {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
      }

      .box .row.content {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="box">
    <h1 class="row header">LightningChart Spectrogram Test #1</h1>

    <!-- Create div to render the chart into-->
    <div id="target" class="row content"></div>

    <!--IIFE assembly (lcjs.iife.js) is a standalone JS file, 
      which does not need any build tools, 
      such as NPM, to be installed-->
    <!--Script source must be defined in it's own script tag-->
    <script src="lcjs.iife.js"></script>

    <!--Actual chart related script tag-->
    <script>
      // Replace the contents of this script tag if you want to test code from our examples:
      // https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/

      // Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
      const {
        AxisTickStrategies,
        LUT,
        PalettedFill,
        Themes,
        emptyLine,
        lightningChart,
        regularColorSteps,
      } = lcjs; //Note: @arction/lcjs is not needed here, when using IIFE assembly

      // Create a XY Chart.
      const chart = lightningChart()
        .ChartXY({
          // Set the chart into a div with id, 'target'.
          // Chart's size will automatically adjust to div's size.
          container: "target",
        })
        .setTitle("LightningChart Spectrogram Test #2"); // Set chart title

      // Set the tick strategy for the x-axis to DateTimeTickStrategy
      chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime);

      // Prepare sample data
      const COLUMNS = 100;
      const ROWS = 10;
      const MAX_INTENSITY_VALUE = 360;
      const sampleData = Array.from({ length: ROWS }, () =>
        Array.from({ length: COLUMNS }, () =>
          Math.random() > 0.5
            ? parseInt(Math.random() * MAX_INTENSITY_VALUE)
            : NaN
        )
      );

      const start = { x: 0, y: 0.1 };
      const step = { x: 2000, y: 0.39 };

      // Create a series
      const series = chart
        .addHeatmapGridSeries({
          columns: COLUMNS,
          rows: ROWS,
          start,
          step,
          dataOrder: "rows",
          heatmapDataType: "intensity",
        })
        .setIntensityInterpolation("disabled")
        .setFillStyle(
          new PalettedFill({
            lookUpProperty: "value",
            lut: new LUT({
              steps: regularColorSteps(
                0,
                MAX_INTENSITY_VALUE,
                chart.getTheme().examples.coldHotColorPalette
              ),
              interpolate: true,
            }),
          })
        )
        .setWireframeStyle(emptyLine);

      chart.addLegendBox().add(chart);

      series.invalidateIntensityValues(sampleData);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

(Update)

It seems like there should be a color option in the LUT for out-of-range data or invalid values, but there isn't.

One trick I came up with is to set the LUT up like this:

```
new LUT({
  steps: [
    { value: -1, color: ColorCSS("Gray") },
    { value: 0, color: ColorCSS("Red") },
    { value: 60, color: ColorCSS("Yellow") },
    { value: 120, color: ColorCSS("LawnGreen") },
    { value: 180, color: ColorCSS("Aqua") },
    { value: 240, color: ColorCSS("Blue") },
    { value: 300, color: ColorCSS("Violet") },
    { value: 360, color: ColorCSS("Red") },
  ],
  interpolate: true,
})
```

In this case, the NaN values are filled with "Gray".
However, it does not look good because it shows -1 in the Legend.

I hope someone can tell me a better way.
Or even a way to remove the -1 from the Legend...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the optional `label` property of `LUTStep`

https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/api-documentation/v4.2.0/interfaces/LUTStep.html#label

Something like

```
new LUT({
  steps: [
    { value: -1, color: ColorCSS("Gray"), label: '' },
    { value: 0, color: ColorCSS("Red") },
    { value: 60, color: ColorCSS("Yellow") },
    { value: 120, color: ColorCSS("LawnGreen") },
    { value: 180, color: ColorCSS("Aqua") },
    { value: 240, color: ColorCSS("Blue") },
    { value: 300, color: ColorCSS("Violet") },
    { value: 360, color: ColorCSS("Red") },
  ],
  interpolate: true,
})
```